# mysqli_begin_transaction work on mysql 5.5.57?

Tags: php, mysqli, server

On localhost:

- mysql server  5.5.58
- php 5.5.9

`mysqli_begin_transaction` works without any problems (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OQoU02zLwFw).

But in the documentation it is written that for work it is required mysql 5.6 or higher: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.begin-transaction.php

---

**My code on the hosting server (`Server version: 5.5.57-cll MySQL`) will work?**

Why the code works on the mysql version  5.5.58 ?

I do not understand something :(

Comment: Shouldn't it work with ancient old MySQL versions? https://web.archive.org/web/20110607113100/http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/commit.html Maybe you should file a bug report at php, maybe they will give you a definitive answer/fix bugs.

Comment: @biziclop , I very much doubt that this is some kind of bug. Can errors in the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.begin-transaction.php ????

Comment: I can imagine absolutely anything from the php guys. https://bugs.php.net/

Comment: @biziclop, Support from my hoster is silent. Maybe it's like a bug. But I doubt it. Ok. i write to php-bug.

Comment: They should give you a definitive explanation. Or you can peek into the source code and try to find that explanation yourself. Anyway, good luck!

Comment: @biziclop this is Documentation Problem https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=75666 . I think that developers should write about this on the site php.net
Or maybe I'm the one stupid: (because I did not understand anything without explanations).